# What is the Java: NoSuchElementException error?

Tags: java, exception

### Looking for help with the following code...

```
package pkgPeople;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateWithoutSerialization {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount(0, 0);
        Person person = new Person();
        String nm;
        int ht;
        int wt;
        long ba;
        double bal;
        File inFile = new File("G:/CS9.27/inperson.txt");
        File outFile = new File("G:/CS9.27/outperson.txt");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outFile);
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(inFile);

        nm = reader.nextLine();
        ht = reader.nextInt();
        wt = reader.nextInt();
        ba = reader.nextLong();
        bal = reader.nextDouble();

        person.setName(nm);
        person.setHeight(ht);
        person.setWeight(wt);
        bankAccount.setAcctID(ba);
        bankAccount.setBalance(bal);


        System.out.println(person.toString());

        //Write the attributes in ASCII to a file
        writer.printf("%s is the name of the person.\r\n",nm);
        writer.printf("%d inches is the height of %s.\r\n",ht, nm);
        writer.printf("%d pounds is the weight of %s\r\n",wt,nm);
        writer.printf("%d dollars is the balance of %s\r\n", bal, nm);
        writer.printf("%l is the ID of the bank account.\r\n", ba);



    }

}
```

---

Upon running, i get this exception..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
at pkgPeople.CreateWithoutSerialization.main(CreateWithoutSerialization.java:23)
```

---

Is this a file error? Have tried multiple fixes but still stuck.

Comment: Can you provide code for Person class?

Comment: What have you tried and im curious to find out in your words, what the stacktrace is *telling* you?

Comment: Are you sure that inperson.txt contains all necessary information? Can you provide this file?

Comment: have tried creating a few spare lines in my inperson.txt

Comment: it is just a blank file...i dont know how to find the stacktrace.

Comment: So, you're trying to read data from blank file. Am I right?

Comment: May be you need to first check whether files are already present at given location and if present what are the access attributes for those files i.e. whether files are read-only, hidden,etc.

Comment: Yes, MAKKAM, it's a blank file

Comment: @D. Spigle - the fact that your input line is empty is most likely the cause of your problem.  See my answer.

Comment: If its a blank file, there's your answer. There is no next line so the scanner throws an exception. Test if you have a next line before calling it if you wish to avoid the exception, or gracefully deal with the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a beginner in a programming language, you need to learn how to use the documentation and resources made readily available for that language.

If you look at the javadoc for the method you are using [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) you would soon realize that the problem is that there is not a new line character for the `Scanner` to read in a line. Check your input file and make sure it meets the specifications. If you are sure your input file is correct you can do some debugging by using the file API to make sure the input File exists before attempting to use it as input for the Scanner.

All of the information you need is readily available in the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).

Answer (score 5):

The exception is being thrown in the call to `reader.nextLine()`  According to [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()), this means that `nextLine()` could not find a next line.

Based on a careful reading of the javadoc, I think that this means that your input file is empty.  You could test this by calling `hasNextLine()` before the call to `nextLine()`.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... I there are two things which are missing here....

Now the `NoSuchElementException` comes when **input is exhausted** . It need not to be related to `nextLine()`. So check whether for the following number of reads

```
nm = reader.nextLine();
ht = reader.nextInt();
wt = reader.nextInt();
ba = reader.nextLong();
bal = reader.nextDouble();
```

You have equal number of lines in your inperson.txt

**Also**
When done writing ... do this also..

```
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Otherwise you won't see any output file... :)

good luck