# Why am I getting this exception?

Tags: java, exception

i'm running my program, and trying to launch the "help" menu from the program being run from that program (if that makes any sense!). But I'm getting a "NoSuchElement" exception, one that isn't even called in my `try {} catch()`, in either program!
What I'm doing is;
Running the program. Typing "create" to launch the commandCreate class. I then type in "help" to launch the help menu. But I get the NoSuchElement exception. If anyone is able to help me with this, my two programs are below. Thank you.

### main.java

```
// main.java
import java.io.*;

public class Main extends API {
      boolean _active = true;
     String _username = System.getProperty("user.name").toLowerCase();
     String _os = System.getProperty("os.name").trim().toLowerCase();

    public Main() {
         try {
            while(_active) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                print(_username + "@" + _os + ":~$ ");
                String command = br.readLine();
                    if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("create")) {
                        new commandCreate();
                    /*} else if(command.equals("compile")) {
                        new commandCompile();*/
                    } else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("help")) {
                        println("Commands");
                        println(" create              - Creates .java files, does not compile.");
                        //println(" compile             - Creates .java files, compiles on creation.");
                        println(" exit                - Exits program");
                        println(" help                - Shows help documentation.");
                    } else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                        print("Are you sure you want to exit? (Y/N) ");
                        String exit = br.readLine();
                        if(exit.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                        exit();
                        } else {
                        println("Cancelled!");
                        }
                    } else if(command.isEmpty()) {

                    } else {
                        println("\"" + command + "\" does not exist. Please review the \"help\" menu");
                    }
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            println("There was a problem: " + ex);
            }
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     new Main();
    }
}
```

### commandCreate.java

```
// commandCreate.java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class commandCreate {
    boolean _active = true;
   String _username = System.getProperty("user.name").toLowerCase();
   String _os = System.getProperty("os.name").trim().toLowerCase();
   String fileName, create, option;

    public commandCreate() {
        try {
            System.out.print(_username + "@" + _os + ":~/create$ ");
            Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
                String userLine = kbd.nextLine();

            Scanner read = new Scanner(userLine);
                option = read.next();
                fileName = read.next();

            FileWriter create = new FileWriter(new File("Created Files/" + fileName + ".java"));

            if(userLine.equals(option + " " + fileName)) {
                if(option.equals("-a")) {
                    // Option = -a, creates standard file with main class.
                    create.write("public class " + fileName + " {\n");
                    create.write("  public static void main(String[] args) {\n");
                    create.write("      System.out.println(\"Welcome to your new program!\");\n");
                    create.write("  }\n");
                    create.write("}");
                } else if(option.equals("-c")) {
                    // Option = -c , creates standard file with overloaded constructor & main class.
                    create.write("public class " + fileName + " {\n");
                    create.write("  public " + fileName + "() {\n");
                    create.write("      System.out.println(\"Welcome to your new program!\");\n");
                    create.write("  }\n");
                    create.write("\n");
                    create.write("  public static void main(String[] args) {\n");
                    create.write("      new " + fileName + "();\n");
                    create.write("  }\n");
                    create.write("}");
                } else if(option.equals("-j")) {
                    // Option = -j, creates GUI within constructor w/ single JLabel.
                    create.write("import javax.swing.*;\n");
                    create.write("import java.awt.*;\n");
                    create.write("import java.awt.event.*;\n");
                    create.write("\n");
                    create.write("public class " + fileName + " extends JFrame {\n");
                    create.write("  private static final int HEIGHT = 50;\n");
                    create.write("  private static final int WIDTH = 400;\n");
                    create.write("\n");
                    create.write("  private JLabel welcomeJ;\n");
                    create.write("\n");
                    create.write("  public " + fileName + "() {\n");
                    create.write("    super(\"Welcome to your program - " + fileName + "\");\n");
                    create.write("      Container pane = getContentPane();\n");
                    create.write("    setLayout(new FlowLayout());\n");
                    create.write("\n");
                    create.write("      welcomeJ = new JLabel(\"Welcome To Your Program!\", SwingConstants.CENTER);\n");
                    create.write("\n");
                    create.write("      pane.add(welcomeJ);\n");
                    create.write("\n");
                    create.write("     setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);\n");
                    create.write("     setVisible(true);\n");
                    create.write("     setResizable(false);\n");
                    create.write("     setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);\n");
                    create.write("  }\n");
                    create.write("\n");
                    create.write("  public static void main(String[] args) {\n");
                    create.write("      new " + fileName + "();\n");
                    create.write("  }\n");
                    create.write("}");
                }
            } else if(userLine.equalsIgnoreCase("help")) {
                System.out.println("Commands");
                System.out.println("  Syntax: [-option] [filename]");
                System.out.println("      -a [filename]      [Program: main class]");
                System.out.println("      -c [filename]      [Program: overloaded constructor, main class]");
                System.out.println("      -j [filename]      [Program: GUI: overloaded constructor, main class]");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error in syntax. Please review the \"help\" menu");
            }
            create.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There was an error: " + e);
        } catch(InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("There was an error: " + ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new commandCreate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your exception stacktrace.

Comment: Not sure on how to stacktrace, really.

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd strongly consider using a templating library rather than embed all those strings. At the very least refactor out each chunk of writes into their own method to make dealing with the mainline code easier.

Comment: see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852910/java-nosuchelementexception-help) helps you..

Comment: @NathanKreider: A "stacktrace" is the all the text spit out by the JVM around "NoSuchElement". It contains the line number that the exception occured on.

Comment: I have a catch in place, so I don't get any errors as such. I'll research the Stacktrace.

Comment: In order to track down these sorts of issues, you need to change `println("There was a problem: " + ex)` to `ex.printStackTrace()`, and `System.out.println("There was an error: " + e)` to `e.printStackTrace()`, and so on. Otherwise, you just won't have enough information about the exception to figure out what happened.

Comment: (And for that matter, you probably shouldn't `catch` these exceptions anyway; or at least, your `catch`-blocks should re-`throw` them. If you don't know what they are -- and you clearly don't -- then how do you know it's O.K. to swallow them and proceed?)

Comment: Okay, I changed it to what you suggested, and I got this error when trying to execute the "help" command.
`Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:855)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1364)
 at commandCreate.<init>(commandCreate.java:18)
 at Main.<init>(Main.java:16)
 at Main.main(Main.java:45)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your stack-trace, the problem is here:

```
            Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
                String userLine = kbd.nextLine();

            Scanner read = new Scanner(userLine);
                option = read.next();
                fileName = read.next();             // <--- exception here
```

What this bit of code does is this:

- it reads a line from standard-input, and saves it in `userLine`.
- it reads two whitespace-delimited tokens from `userLine`, and saves them as `option` and `filename`.

So the problem is that the line from standard-input doesn't actually *have* two whitespace-delimited tokens. It needs to look something like `-j file.txt`, but instead maybe it just looks like `-j`, or like `file.txt`.

Comment: Yeah, I gathered it could be something to do with that scanner.. is there a way I could make it so only runs the "read" scanner if there is an input of two strings? So that I can have both of the if's?

Comment: @NathanKreider: I suppose you could check `if(java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(".*\\S\\s+\\S.*", userLine))`. That would ensure that `userLine` contains at least two non-whitespace characters that are separated by whitespace.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you! Now to shorten it and use an import.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a problem in the superclass named API.  Look there.

Comment: The API class contains 3 methods only, none conflicting with anything.